# ListView divider height content depedent

Tags: android, listview

I have an *expandable* ListView with a bit more complex row layout (multiple TextViews, ImageViews etc). 
As an adapter I use an extension of a CursorAdapter to query the data from a SQLite database in my app. 
From my database I query ~100 entries which are then display in the ListView and ordered by the date of the event. 
If now the time between two consecutive events is larger than e.g. 4 days, I want the spacing between the rows be a bit larger than in the other case.

How do I implement this? In the newView method of the cursorAdapter I create a ViewHolder and set a tag to it. In the bindView method I do the filling of the textviews, imageviews etc. The getView method is not overridden in my current implementation, so I do not do any work there.

Should I move the cursor in the bindView method back to the previous position, get the date of the previous entry and then move the cursor to the original position, check the date difference and then change some layout params? Is this a good approach? And which layout params would I have to change? The divider height is a global feature for the listView and cannot be changed for only some views.

Comment: if they are sorted by time then you need to check only one previous entry, and if it is older that 4 days apply an extra "top" margin / padding on the current entry view

Comment: And where should I do this check? In the bindView method? And is it safe to move the cursor around, i.e. is it guaranteed that I get the correct entry with this method?

Comment: inside `bindChildView`, you can always use `getPosition` before any cursor movement and `moveToPosition` afterwards

Comment: You could instead have a row (Array item) for every day, regardless of whether an event occured or not... then just make a "blank" day be a very short, blank row... so you will naturally get gaps that realistically represent gaps in time.  Can you have more than one event on the same day?  If so, then there goes my idea.

Comment: Yes, there could be multiple events per day. Sorry for being not specific enough!

Comment: @pskink Works like a charm. Do you want to post this as an answer?